# Specify ordinals of C++ exported functions in a DLL

Tags: c++, dll, export

I am writing a DLL with mixed C/C++ code. I want to specify the ordinals of the functions I'm exporting. So I created a .DEF file that looks like this

```
LIBRARY LEONMATH

EXPORTS

    sca_alloc   @1
    vec_alloc   @2
    mat_alloc   @3

    sca_free    @4
    vec_free    @5
    mat_free    @6

    ...
```

I would like to specify the ordinals of my C++ functions and class methods too. I have tried using the Dependency Walker to add the mangled names of my functions to the .DEF file:

```
    ??0CScalar@@QAE@XZ      @25
    ??0CScalar@@QAE@O@Z     @26
    ??0CScalar@@QAE@ABV0@@Z @27
    ??1CScalar@@QAE@XZ      @28
```

But this has failed. Any ideas why this could be happening?

---

**EDIT:** kauppi made a good observation, so I'm adding more information to the question.

- **Platform:** Windows (and I'm not interested in portability)
- **Compiler:** Microsoft's C++ compiler (I'm using VS2005)
- **Why I want to do this?:** Using the ordinals has the advantage of letting me call exported C++ functions from C code.

Comment: I think you should refine your question and at least tell what platform you are using (Symbian?) and why you need to do that. I can't see a use case for your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I don't have experience with ordinals (which look like some ugly, compiler-specific thing), but I can help you with making C++/C code compatible.

Suppose, in C++, that your header file looks like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    void foo(int);
    int bar(int);
    double bar(double);
    void baz(MyClass);
};
```

You can make it C-compatible by doing the following:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define EXTERN_C extern "C"
// Class definition here; unchanged
#else
#define EXTERN_C
typedef struct MyClass MyClass;
#endif

EXTERN_C void MyClass_foo (MyClass*, int);
EXTERN_C int MyClass_bar_int (MyClass*, int);
EXTERN_C double MyClass_bar_double (MyClass*, double);
EXTERN_C void MyClass_baz (MyClass*, MyClass*);
```

In the C++ source file, you just define the various `extern "C"` functions to pass to the desired member functions, like this (this is only one; the rest work similarly)

```
extern "C" void MyClass_foo (MyClass* obj, int i)
{
  obj->foo(i);
}
```

The code will then have a C interface, without having to change the C++ code at all (except for declarations in the header; but those could also be moved to another file `"myclass_c.h"` or the like). All the functions declared/defined extern "C" won't be mangled, so you can do other operations on them easily. You will also probably want functions to construct/destroy instances of MyClass (you can, of course, use `new`/`delete` for this).

Answer (score 2):

You said "Using the ordinals has the advantage of letting me call exported C++ functions from C code." , I am sorry to say that this is incorrect.

C++ class member functions have special calling convention which requires an invisible **this** value passed in an implementation-specific register/parameter. And also you need a class instance to pass, which you can not accomplish in C.

The only 2 uses of this that I know, are faster dynamic linking of the DLL and smaller Import Table. Just inspect mfc70.dll in system32 directory with the dependancy walker.

Comment: Isn't it possible to add the `this` value to the parameter list? And, if it can't be done directly... can I do it using the inline assembler?

Comment: Well, anything is possible in "C" but I did not do such a thing. If it is possible, it will require non-portable constructs and/or ASM. So you better do everything in C++. The method proposed by coppro is also good, You just have to add MyClass_New and MyClass_Delete that uses void* for "this"...